# Not updating in mysql , php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Ok, So I am creating a attendance system and I want to mark a student present or absent, this is my code

```
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$present = $_POST['present'];


}
$test3= "SELECT * FROM course_attendance, students, courses, attendance WHERE course_attendance.course_id=courses.course_id AND course_attendance.week_id=attendance.week_number_id AND course_attendance.student_id= students.student_id AND courses.course_id='101' AND attendance.week_number_id='2' ";
$result = mysql_query($test3)  or die(mysql_error());


echo "</br><table border='1' align='center'><tr> <th><strong>Student ID</strong></th> <th><strong>First Name </strong></th> <th><strong>Last Name</strong></th> <th><strong>Present</strong></th> </tr> ";

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo"<form name='Biology_lecture11.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<tr><td width='100' align='center'>" .$rows['student_id'].
"</td><td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['fname'].
"</td><td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['lname'].
"</td><td><input type='text' name='present' value=" .$rows['present'] . ">";

}
echo "</table>";
?>
 <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'  >
   </form>

  <?php 


   $sql="UPDATE course_attendance SET present='$present' WHERE course_id='101' AND week_id='2' ";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  if($result){
      echo "Successfully logged the attendance";
  }
  else {
      echo"ERROR";

  }
  ?>
```

The problem is , that it does not update the present field in the database, anyone know whats wrong

Comment: Did you connect to the database ?

Comment: Yes i am connected to the database

Comment: It looks like you are updating present value for all students since your only WHERE checks are the `course_id` and the `week_id`. If your while loop contains more than one record, you will have multiple instances of the element `<input type='text' name='present'...`.

Comment: Also the table in MySQL is course_attendance: attendance_id, week_id (FK), course_id(FK), student_id(FK), present

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pw3ned. You're also uncoditionally setting the presence of every student in the class every time the form is submitted, which is probably NOT what you intend to do.

Comment: @Garreh so what does that mean?

Comment: Did you really name your son `Robert'); DROP TABLE course_attendance; --` ? Oh yes, Little Bobby Tables, we call him

Comment: It means, according to your logic, if student [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) is first in the list and is in the class, then everyone else is to.... or is anyone in the class? No one exists anymore! Better cancel school.

Comment: Oh ok i get what your saying, yea it updates all records , not specific ones

Comment: Please, **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query` in new applications. As you've demonstrated here, you've created a massive security hole by not properly escaping your SQL values. It only takes a half hour to figure out [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and if used correctly, problems like this do not happen.

Comment: Building on @tadman's comment, [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) has been depreciated for PHP 5.5.0. Switch to `PDO` or [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. This will assign each student a unique `present` value, which is then checked on postback and if set, it is cleaned and used to update the student record in attendance.

I also extracted echo'd HTML in the PHP to HTML, and moved your form outside of your table (it can cause issues in some browsers).

```
<?php
// Update present values
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    // Get a list of student ids to check
    $idsResult = mysql_query("SELECT student_id from students");

    while($idRow = mysql_fetch_array($idsResult))
    {
       // if the textbox for this student is set 
       if(isset($_POST['present'.$idRow['student_id']]) && !empty($_POST['present'.$idRow['student_id']]))
       {
          // Clean the user input, then escape and update the database
          $cleanedPresent = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['present'.$idRow['student_id']]));
          $sql = "UPDATE course_attendance SET present='".mysql_real_escape_string($present)."' WHERE course_id='101' AND week_id='2' AND student_id=".$idRow['student_id'];
          $result = mysql_query($sql);

          if($result){
            echo "Successfully logged the attendance for ID ".$idRow['student_id'];
          }
          else {
            echo "ERROR updating on ID ".$idRow['student_id'];
          }
       }
    }
}

$test3= "SELECT * FROM course_attendance, students, courses, attendance WHERE course_attendance.course_id=courses.course_id AND course_attendance.week_id=attendance.week_number_id AND course_attendance.student_id= students.student_id AND courses.course_id='101' AND attendance.week_number_id='2' ";
$result = mysql_query($test3)  or die(mysql_error());
?>
<form name='Biology_lecture11.php' method='post'>
</br>
<table border='1' align='center'>
  <tr>
    <th><strong>Student ID</strong></th>
    <th><strong>First Name </strong></th>
    <th><strong>Last Name</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Present</strong></th>
  </tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr><td width='100' align='center'>" .$rows['student_id'].
  "</td><td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['fname'].
  "</td><td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['lname'].
  "</td><td><input type='text' name='present".$rows['student_id']."' value=" .$rows['present'] . ">";
}
?>
</table>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Alternative (better) method: If the present value can be set to a simple 0/1 or true/false, then it would be easier to use a checkbox for each student. In postback, you can then retrieve an array of values from checking each checkbox indicating students who are present, and then update the database table in one query. That also prevents from malicious text input.

Alternative code:

```
<?php
// Update present values
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    // Get a list of student ids to check
    $idsResult = mysql_query("SELECT student_id from students");

    $presentIds = array();
    $absentIds = array();
    while($idRow = mysql_fetch_array($idsResult))
    {
       // If the student's checkbox is checked, add it to the presentIds array.
       if(isset($_POST['present'.$idRow['student_id']]))
       {
         $presentIds[] = $idRow['student_id'];
       }
       else
       {
         $absentIds[] = $idRow['student_id'];
       }
    }

      // Convert array to string for query
      $idsAsString = implode(",", $presentIds);

      // You can set present to whatever you want. I used 1. 
      $sql = "UPDATE course_attendance SET present='1' WHERE course_id='101' AND week_id='2' AND student_id IN (".$idsAsString.")";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);

      if($result){
        echo "Successfully logged the attendance for IDs ".$idsAsString;
      }
      else {
        echo "ERROR updating on IDs ".$idsAsString;
      }


      // OPTIONAL: Mark absent students as '0' or whatever other value you want
      $absentIdsAsString = implode(",", $absentIds);
      // You can set present to whatever you want. I used 1. 
      $absentQuery = "UPDATE course_attendance SET present='0' WHERE course_id='101' AND week_id='2' AND student_id IN (".$absentIdsAsString.")";
      $absentResult = mysql_query($absentQuery);

      if($absentResult){
        echo "Successfully logged absence for IDs ".$absentIdsAsString;
      }
      else {
        echo "ERROR updating absence on IDs ".$absentIdsAsString;
      }

}

$test3= "SELECT * FROM course_attendance, students, courses, attendance WHERE course_attendance.course_id=courses.course_id AND course_attendance.week_id=attendance.week_number_id AND course_attendance.student_id= students.student_id AND courses.course_id='101' AND attendance.week_number_id='2' ";
$result = mysql_query($test3)  or die(mysql_error());
?>
<form name='Biology_lecture11.php' method='post'>
</br>
<table border='1' align='center'>
  <tr>
    <th><strong>Student ID</strong></th>
    <th><strong>First Name </strong></th>
    <th><strong>Last Name</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Present</strong></th>
  </tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr><td width='100' align='center'>" .$rows['student_id'].
  "</td><td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['fname'].
  "</td><td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['lname'].
  "</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='present".$rows['student_id']."' ";

  // NOTE: REPLACE 1 with whatever value you store in the database for being present. 
  // I used 1 since the update at the top of the code uses 0 and 1.
  if($rows['present']=='1')
  {
    echo "checked='checked' ";
  }
  // With a checkbox, you don't need to assign it a value.
  echo "value=" .$rows['present'];

  echo ">";
}
?>
</table>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth I am going to try this out

Comment: @Gareth sorry to be a pain, do u know how to code it with a checkbox instead of a textbox

Comment: @JasjootMuhdar Yes, I will add it to the answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you so much in advance, I got my final year project demo in a few days ,  u would have saved my life !

Comment: @JasjootMuhdar Please check out my alternative code. You can replace 0 and 1 with whatever you currently use to mark a student as present in the database.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this out now

Comment: Actually it does ,google chrome gives me problems sometimes, THANK YOU , it actually works @Garreh full ratings to you Thank You once again !!!

Answer (score 0):

you have taken a form inside table tag and inside while loop this will not work, here is correct code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $present = $_POST['present'];

    $sql="UPDATE course_attendance SET present='$present' WHERE course_id='101' AND week_id='2' ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    if($result) {
        echo "Successfully logged the attendance";
    }
    else {
      echo"ERROR";
    }

}

?>

<form name='Biology_lecture11.php' method='post'>
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
    <th><strong>Student ID</strong></th>
    <th><strong>First Name </strong></th>
    <th><strong>Last Name</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Present</strong></th>
</tr>

<?php

$test3= "SELECT * FROM course_attendance, students, courses, attendance WHERE course_attendance.course_id=courses.course_id AND course_attendance.week_id=attendance.week_number_id AND course_attendance.student_id= students.student_id AND courses.course_id='101' AND attendance.week_number_id='2' ";
$result = mysql_query($test3)  or die(mysql_error());

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<tr><td width='100' align='center'>" .$rows['student_id']."</td>
      <td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['fname']."</td>
      <td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['lname']."</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='present' value=" .$rows['present']."></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'  >
</form>
```

Comment: This _won't_ work. There is still duplication of form elements in the while loop.

Comment: @Sumit Thanks for writing it out, but however it still does not update the fields for each specific student , this is a weird, as the code logically seems correct

Comment: @JasjootMuhdar check my edited answer there was `</td></tr>` missing

Comment: Nope not working , i dont know why ! this is really annoying , i appreciate you spending time on this guys @SumitBijvani

Comment: Do you think it might make it easier if I had checkboxes instead

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I see is, that you put this:

```
echo"<form name='Biology_lecture11.php' method='post'>";
```

in your while-loop. So it is put out more than one time. Try writing that part in the row before your loop.

Comment: Second Problem i found is, the Submit-Button is named "Submit" and in the beginning you ask for $_POST['submit']. They should both have the same name ( watch for upper & lowercase)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues I see:

1:  You're UPDATE code is running every time the page is loaded.  Move you update block into the if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {} block.
2:  When you print out the students, you create an input called "present" for every student.  If you were to fill this in and submit the data, only the last field will be added to the database.
3:  You're not updating a specific student.  I would change the input field to a checkbox and name it "present[$rows[student_id]]".
Then, once the page is being processed, loop through the key/values of $_POST['present'].   and update any students that are in it.

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST['present']) as $student_id) {
    if (is_numeric($student_id)) {
        $sql="UPDATE course_attendance SET present='true' WHERE course_id='101' AND week_id='2' and student_id='$student_id'";
    }
}
```

You'll have to modify the UPDATE if the attendance table isn't automatically filled in with students.  If every student isn't already there, you'll have to run a query to see if they exist.  If they don't insert the row.  If they do, update the row.
4: Move the  opening tag to before the opening of the table and OUTSIDE of the student loop.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to take in consideration: First, you have form element dupplication. As the comments above said, take out the line

```
echo"<form name='Biology_lecture11.php' method='post'>";
```

from the loop.

Second, the `UPDATE` statatement *updates* all the students, you need a `WHERE` token in your SQL statement. Something like this:

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$present = $_POST['present'];


}
$test3= "SELECT * FROM course_attendance, students, courses, attendance WHERE course_attendance.course_id=courses.course_id AND course_attendance.week_id=attendance.week_number_id AND course_attendance.student_id= students.student_id AND courses.course_id='101' AND attendance.week_number_id='2' ";
$result = mysql_query($test3)  or die(mysql_error());


echo "</br><table border='1' align='center'><tr> <th><strong>Student ID</strong></th> <th><strong>First Name </strong></th> <th><strong>Last Name</strong></th> <th><strong>Present</strong></th> </tr> ";
    echo"<form name='Biology_lecture11.php' method='post'>";    
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td width='100' align='center'>" .$rows['student_id'].
"</td><td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['fname'].
"</td><td width='120' align='center'>" .$rows['lname'].
"</td><td><input type='text' name='present' value=" .$rows['present'] . ">";

}
echo "</table>";
?>
 <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'  >
   </form>

  <?php 


   $sql="UPDATE course_attendance SET present='$present' WHERE course_id='101' AND week_id='2' AND student_id =  the_student_id";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  if($result){
      echo "Successfully logged the attendance";
  }
  else {
      echo"ERROR";

  }
  ?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Im checking it out now , thanks for taking the time to help , will let you know if it works !

Comment: it will not work. because you have put `form` tag inside `table` and close it after table tag